# ExactTarget Web Service API & Node.js

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap

I am trying to consume ExactTarget Web Service API from node.js using node-soap. With other webservices, I instantiate a client with the WSDL

> ```
> var soap = require('soap');
> var url = "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL";
> var args = {"symbol" : "DOX"};
> soap.createClient(url,function(err,client){
>     if (err) throw err;
>     console.log(client.describe());
> })
> ```
>
> The above code-fragment prints out something like this

```
{ StockQuote:     
    { StockQuoteSoap: { GetQuote: [Object] },
      StockQuoteSoap12: { GetQuote: [Object] } 
    } 
}
```

Looking at the output, I can invoke a WebService Method like

```
   client.StockQuote.StockQuoteSoap.GetQuote(args,function(err,result)
```

When I try to instantiate a client with the ExactTarget URL https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl, the `client.describe` call fails with the message

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

The node-soap documentation shows the following way to invoke a WebService method

> Client.service.port.method(args, callback) - call a method using a
>   specific service and port

How do I invoke a WebService method such as Create? Specifically, what do I specify for `service` & `port`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We haven't had much luck implementing this library with exacttarget's SOAP webservices.  We suggest using [ws.js](https://github.com/yaronn/ws.js).

Using this library, you can build out your SOAP packets directly. Here is some sample code to `describe` the `subscriber` object.

```
var ws = require('ws.js');
var Http = ws.Http;
var Security = ws.Security;
var UsernameToken = ws.UsernameToken;

  var request = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">' +   
                      '<soapenv:Header>' +
                           '<ns1:fueloauth xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com">[USE YOUR OAUTH TOKEN]</ns1:fueloauth>' +
                      '</soapenv:Header>' +
                      '<soapenv:Body>' +
                      '<DefinitionRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">' +
                         '<DescribeRequests>' +
                            '<ObjectDefinitionRequest>' +
                               '<ObjectType>Subscriber</ObjectType>' +
                            '</ObjectDefinitionRequest>' +
                         '</DescribeRequests>' +
                      '</DefinitionRequestMsg>' +
                   '</soapenv:Body>' +
                '</soapenv:Envelope>'


var ctx =  { request: request 
           , url: "https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx"
           , action: "Describe"
           , contentType: "text/xml" 
           }


var handlers =  [ new Http() ]

ws.send(handlers, ctx, function(ctx) {                    
  console.log("response: " + ctx.response);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

We're not having any issues using SOAP and Node.js. We use [node-soap](https://github.com/milewise/node-soap) for this purpose and it's working well for us.

If you're having issues, you should just test sending a soap request envelope locally using cURL. This is an easy way to confirm your requests are structured correctly. Save your SOAP request as an XML file named 'request.xml' and then call it from the command line using cURL:

```
 curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction: XXXXXX" -d @request.xml https://webservice.test.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx
```

Where **SOAPAction** uses the appropriate verb for the request; Create, Retrieve, Extract, etc. For example: `"SOAPAction: Retrieve"`.

Answer (score 1):

The [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) module has been updated recently and is working.

```
var soap = require('soap');
var soapWSDL = "https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl";

soap.createClient(soapWSDL, function (err, client) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(client.describe() );
});


// console.log  => 
{ PartnerAPI: 
 { Soap: 
  { Create: [Object],
    Retrieve: [Object],
    Update: [Object],
    Delete: [Object],
    Query: [Object],
    Describe: [Object],
    Execute: [Object],
    Perform: [Object],
    Configure: [Object],
    Schedule: [Object],
    VersionInfo: [Object],
    Extract: [Object],
    GetSystemStatus: [Object] } } }
```