# How to use node-fuel to add/update subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm looking for a way to add and update subscribers in a list, using the nodejs [module](https://github.com/ExactTarget/node-fuel).

Is there an easy way?

Thanks a lot,
Philmod

Answer (score 2):

I was originally trying to do the same but ended up using Data Extensions instead. The REST api plays well with them and you can use them a lot like lists from what I've seen.

Comment: Data Extensions are a good option and they are exposed via the REST APIs which can be accessed using node-fuel.  In order to access the Subscriber object, the SOAP API would need to be used but I haven't seen any examples of using ExactTarget's SOAP service from node yet.

Comment: It looks like someone got it working with [node-soap](https://github.com/milewise/node-soap): [http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25004/exacttarget-web-service-api-node-js](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25004/exacttarget-web-service-api-node-js).

Answer (score 0):

Node-Fuel was created to assist with REST calls. Updating subscribers using Node-Fuel is not supported, as subscribers is currently a SOAP API.