# ExactTarget Data Extract with SOAP using Node.js

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, node.js

I am trying to create a [data extract activity with the SOAP web service](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_data_extract_activity_with_the_soap_web_service_api/) API using nodejs. Have you been able to find any open source libraries related to this, i am happy to contribute back if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

We currently have a closed project we are working on that utilizes [`xml2js`](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) which helps streamline some of the calls.

Currently, the configuration I am using to simplify the calls is below:

Requests:

```
var envelope = {
    '$': {
        "xmlns": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
        "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    },
    'Header': {
        'fueloauth': {
            '$': {
                "xmlns": "http://exacttarget.com"
            },
            "_": token
        }
    },
    "Body": request
}


var buildOptions = {
    rootName: "Envelope",
    headless: true
}

var builder = new xml2js.Builder(buildOptions);
return builder.buildObject(envelope);
```

Response:

```
var parseOptions = {
    trim: true,
    normalize: true,
    explicitArray: false,
    ignoreAttrs: true
};
```

--Hopefully we will be able to open source the project in the next month or so.--

**Update**
The Fuel Node SOAP client library has been opened up - you can find it on Github https://github.com/ExactTarget/Fuel-Node-SOAP

I recommend checking it out.

Comment: I am a total soap noob and have been building my request with xml like http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/25045/10905 - trying to create a subscriber data extraction activity. http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/tracking_extract_output/subscribers/

Comment: My biggest suggestion would be to test with SOAP UI - makes it easy to get the soap right. http://www.soapui.org/

Answer (score 0):

**node.js client for the exactTarget SOAP service**

https://github.com/Datahero/node-exacttarget